# Does anyone know of an entire function $f$ such that $f(x,y)=0\iff\exists n\in\Bbb{N}\left[y=nx\right]$?

Tags: functions

I tried constructing $f$ as $f(x,y) = n\left(\frac{y}{x} \right)$ where $n(a)=\lim \limits_{x \to a} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x}$, but I can't figure out how to remove the discontinuities when $x$ or $y$ is $0$. In these cases, I'd be fine with the function taking on any value (although preferably not $0$).

**Clarification:**
I apologize if I am using "entire function" incorrectly. I intend $x$ and $y$ to be two separate complex arguments to $f$. I am seeking an $f$ such that the multi-variable Taylor series converges for all choices of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What do you mean "entire?"  Are $x,y$ complex variables? "Entire function" usually references a function of one complex variable. Do you mean where $f(x+yi)=0\iff \exists n\in\mathbb N(y=nx)$? If so, then no such entire function exists since any such function is zero on $\{x+xi\}$ so it is zero everywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry. I mainly play with mathematics recreationally, so my question may not make sense. $x$ and $y$ are intended to be two separate complex arguments to $f$. I imagined the notion of "entire function" could be generalized to any arity by computing the power series and ensuring that it converges everywhere on the complex plane for both arguments. Is that incoherent?

Comment: Don't clarify the question in comments, clarify the question. Answerers don't know to read the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not even possible to have $f$ continuous on all of $\mathbb C^2$.

That is because the condition requires $f(0,1)\neq 0$ and $f(1/n,1)=0$ for all natural $n$.

Comment: Great point! Just to make sure I understand, this is because if $f$ is continuous at $(0, 1)$, then $f(0, 1) = \lim \limits_{(x, y) \to (0, 1)} f(x, y)$. Alas, $f(1/n, 1) = 0$ for all natural $n$, so if $\lim \limits_{(x, y) \to (0, 1)} f(x,y)$ exists, it must be $0$.